# How to solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'' -y' +(1-x)y=0$$ 
where $y_{1}=e^x$, $y(-1/2)=0$, $y'(-1/2)=2$.
I think that $y_h=e^{ax}$
$$[a^{2}x -a +(1-x) ]e^{ax}=0$$
$$[x(a^2-1) +(1-a)]e^{ax}=0$$

$$a=1$$

$$y_h=Be^x +xCe^x$$

However I realized $xCe^x$ is not solution.

How to solve this ODE?

Comment: Thank you, I understood your idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $x \neq 0$. Then take $y(x) = v (x) y_1(x)$ and notice that $y(x)$ is a solution of your ode if $v(x)$ is solution of $$e^xv''(x) + \left(2e^x - \frac{e^x}{x}\right)v'(x) = 0$$ which is a first order equation for $v'$.